# Symfony class case-sensitivity error

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

I'm new to symfony - just got an app up and running this weekend and playing around trying to get a sense of how to put stuff together.

I created a route with a controller and a template.

**routes.yaml**

```
test:
    path: /test
    controller: App\Controller\test::initialize
```

**test.php** (controller)

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class test extends Controller {

    public function initialize() {

        return new Response("hello test");
    }
}
```

Now I would simply like to rename my class such that it adheres to the convention of class names (capitalized).

```
class test {...} ----> class Test {...}
```

And the route would follow:

```
test:
    path: /test
    controller: App\Controller\Test::initialize  # test becomes Test
```

Simple.

But when I do this I get a runtime error:

`Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: "App\Controller\test" vs "App\Controller\Test".`

I tried clearing the server cache. Dont really understand from where `App\Controller\test` is being read after having renamed all mentions of that class.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Symfony stores a great deal of information (including class names) in a cache.  Normally the cache will update itself but there a few things that will break it.  So just use the nuclear option and remove the cache directory completely.  rm -r var/cache should do the trick.  Run bin/console afterwards to verify all is well.

Comment: Did you also rename test.php to Test.php? Symfony requires the filename case to match the class name's case.

Comment: A combination of the above were the issues. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issues, the above two comment solved my problem.

- Symfony requires that the controller filename match the class
- run `rm -r var/cache` to clear cache beyond that of the `bin/console cache:clear` commmand